# Does the corpus callosum have a significant relationship with motor memories/ muscle memories?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology

With the corpus callosum located in the cerebrum, and motor memories having a closer relationship to the cerebellum (which I'm not quite sure about), is there a significant relationship between the corpus callosum and motor memories? Do motor memories process in one hemisphere and are then shared with the other- if so, how? Thank you so much for your time and patience!

Comment: Almost all parts of the brain have a relationship, but what deems a neuronal relationship significant? Maybe this will help (pay-wall): https://onlinelibrary-wiley-com.ezproxy2.acu.edu.au/doi/abs/10.1002/cne.902470303

Comment: @Andrew thank you for sharing! However, I don't have a user account with ACU . Can anyone sign up or just students? Cheers!

Comment: Apologies, try this link: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/3722441/

Comment: @Andrew got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This [study](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/159144339.pdf) tests the time it takes for patients with damaged corpus callosums to perform intermanual transfer motor tasks.

Patients drew a meaningless figure with one hand, then did it again with the other hand (And vice versa). Thus performing intermanual transfer.

> All three patients displayed a **significant benefit** for transfer from the dominant to the non-dominant hand **but not vice versa** during proximal motor activity.

> ...the proximal transfer behavior was found to be similar for all patients in the healthy group.

From these results, a relationship exsists.